# Dynamically updating content (eg. clicking button updates div) and update url on website without refresh, then stay on the same page on manual refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

So I'm struggling to figure out how to do this and I can't find any answers. I've been searching the whole web for the last two days but haven't found an answer yet.

> **The goal:** I want a dynamic navigation for an admin/dashbaord website that only updates a div (the main view) of a website and updates the url accordinly (eg. pressing on the
> **welcome** menu button loads the `welcome.html` into the
> `#main-view` and the url updates from
> `samplewebsite.com/dashboard` to
> `samplewebsite.com/dashboard/welcome`). Then on refresh, stay on the same website with the loaded content (eg. `samplewebsite.com/dashboard/welcome` still has `welcome.html` in the `#main-view` but doesn't actually navigate to the `welcome.html` file.
>
> **Examples:** [mee6.xyz/moderation](https://mee6.xyz/moderation) or [contacts.google.com](https://contacts.google.com/)

[image]

**What I've already accomplished:** Loading `welcome.html` into `#main-view` and updating the url with /welcome by clicking on a button by doing this:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="/dashboard/welcome" id="welcome-button">Welcome</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#welcome-button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main-view').load(href, function() {
        console.log("Load was performed.");
      });
    history.pushState(null, "Welcome", href);
})
```

I'm using `Flask` with Python where I have the following routing set up:

```
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard_server():
    return render_template("dashboard_server.html")

@app.route('/dashboard/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template("welcome.html")
```

> **The behaviour I experience:** When I click the welcome menu button, `#main-view` updates with the `welcome.html` and the url updates. When I
> refresh the browser though, I takes me to the actual `welcome.html` which makes sense, since it's pointing to this file. That's how I loaded the html into the div in the rist place. But how can I prevent that?
> Also the navigation (back/forward) doesn't work but that's another problem I'll
> adress after I got this figured out.
>
> **What I behaviour I expect:** I want it to stay on the main page with `#main-view` still being filled with `welcome.html`. Then when
> pressing another menu button I want it to update the div and url and
> on the refresh be on the same page with the updated div and so on.

A visual explanation:
[image]

I'm grateful for any kind of help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [pushstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a pretty hacky way to do routing with JavaScript. But here is how I think your problem can be solved:

When user refreshes the page on this url: `/dashboard/welcome`, you should run some js that would grab the `location.pathname` and know that the url must not have the `welcome` part and would redirect the user back to `dashboard` but you would have to add an url parameter to let the js on dashboard page know which page's content to load in the `#main-view` so from `dashboard/welcome` you can redirect the user to an url similar to this: `dashboard?page=welcome`. Now through js on the dashboard page, you need to grab the url parameter `page` and load the content of the `welcome.html` which you already have achieved. Now you should change the url back to `dashboard/welcome` from `dashboard?page=welcome` and push the url to history too.

This approach might have a lot of scenarios where the stie might break. One would be: when your js is evaluating things on `dashboard/welcome` page, the `welcome` page might have already been loaded, so you would have to show a loader or similar to prevent the flash of incorrect content.

I can't think of more scenarios from top of my head. I would suggest you to use some sort of framework/library to take care of routing for you. CRA (create react app), Next.js, Gatsby.js, Nuxt.js are all great libraries that can handle routing in a very robust way so you don't have to worry about that and can focus on the content and styling your applciation. Except CRA, I think all other libraries support static site generation which gives you better SEO overall. But to use these, you need to know React.js or Next.js at least. Best of luck!

Comment: A bit late but I wanted to say thanks. I took your advice and I actually learned Vue.js now and I'm currently building the web app which is soon ready to be deployed and it's waaay cleaner than writing plain javascript code. That helped me to build websites way faster now. Cheers man.

Comment: Good to hear man! Best of luck!